# What is the most important test for a uniform random number generator?

Tags: random

What is the most important test for a uniform random number generator ?  Is there a single most important test or a set?  I am a using some analytically arrived at answers to probability problems and checking the simulation answers obtained through a random generator.  For all the probability problems that I analysed and simulated and checked, they are coming pretty close to the analytical results.

Answer (score 1):

Any single test is inadequate.  A single test will find failures of randomness of one kind, but the generated numbers might still be very orderly in other respects.  So it's best to use a bunch of different tests that look for different patterns.

I'm not sure I understand your use case (and by now you may no longer have the same need), but if you really want to test the quality of a uniform random number generator, you should use a high-quality, up to date test suite such as Pierre L'Ecuyer's [TestU01](http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/tu01.html).  A random number generator that passes all of the tests might still exhibit systematic nonrandom patterns (and if it's a pseudorandom number generating algorithm, it's guaranteed to do so), but the chance that they'd make a difference to your application would be small.

The papers linked at the TestU01 page are very informative, too, as is Melissa O'Neil's [PCG paper](http://www.pcg-random.org/paper.html).  Good books include:

- Kneusel's [*Random Numbers and Computers*](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319776965)
- Johnston's [*Random Number Generators--Principles and Practices*](https://www.degruyter.com/view/product/486349).
- Knuth, Chapter 3 in volume 2 of the 3rd edition of [*The Art of Computer Programming*](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp.html) (still deserves to be called the "bible" of pseudorandom number generation, even though there have been crucial innovations since it was published, so there are better algorithms now.)

(Some partially-similar questions I've answered on another site:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/335203/understanding-different-kinds-of-rngs-tests/407910#407910
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438398/is-there-a-way-to-visualize-the-limited-randomness-of-an-algorithm/439691#439691
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436733/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-good-bad-seed-in-pseudo-random-number-generation/438057#438057 )